# Add address with woocommerce_thankyou hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I want to use a code snippet to add order billing and shipping address to the bottom of the woocommerce thank you page.

I've modified a PHP snippet which does work to add the addresses on another page but it gives a fatal error when used here.

Perhaps someone can tell me where I have gone wrong:

```
function thank_you_add_address(){
        $order_id = absint( get_query_var( 'order-pay' ) );
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
        ?>
        <!-- Display Information -->
        <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
            <address>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_billing_address( __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--email"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </address>

        <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
        <address>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_shipping_address( __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
        </address>
        <?php
          }

    add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'thank_you_add_address');
```

error message is:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_formatted_billing_address() on bool in /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(504) : eval()'d code:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): thank_you_add_address(23078) #1 /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php(80): do_action('woocommerce_tha...', 23078) #4 /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(345): include('/home/u39873847...') #5 /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-content/plugins/woo in /home/u398**/domains/mysite.co.uk/public_html/test3/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(504) : eval()'d code on line 9
There has been a critical error on this website.

Comment: Please share the error message

Answer (score 0):

```
function thank_you_add_address($order_id){
        //create an order instance 
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
        ?>
        <!-- Display Information -->
        <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
            <address>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_billing_address( __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--phone"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-customer-details--email"><?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_email() ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </address>

        <h2 class="woocommerce-column__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
        <address>
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_shipping_address( __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>
        </address>
        <?php
          }

    add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'thank_you_add_address', 10, 1);
```

The hook `woocommerce_thankyou` receives `$order_id` as a parameter. You can use that to create the order object

Comment: Thanks, which bits would I need to change to use $order_id like this ?

Comment: @stephenla Overwrite your code with the above code, have made changes in the hook params and updated

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate that.
I'll see if I can understand the changes !